# matrix with no solution, unique solution and infinite solution

Tags: matrices

\begin{bmatrix}1 & h& h^2 & 1\\ h^2 & h & 1 & 2\\h & h^2 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}

Given the matrix above is an augmented matrix, what is the possible value h where there is no solutions, unique solutions, and infinite solutions?

I have tried

1) reducing the matrix to 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & h& h^2 & 1\\ 0 & h-h^2 & 1-h^2 & 1-h^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1-h^3 & 2-h \end{bmatrix}

2) For infinite soloution $$1-h^3 = 2-h$$
$$h^3-h+1 = 0$$

3) For no solution
$$ 1-h^3 = 0$$
$$ h = 1$$
$$ h -2 = 0 $$
$$h = 2$$

4) For unique solution 
$$ h\neq 1,2$$

I am a bit unsure of whether my solution because it seems weird for my answer of infinite solutions.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. Consider $h=1$. Then we have infinitely many solutions. But you require $h^3-h+1=0$, which is not satisfied by $h=1$.

Comment: Are you sure you did that row-reduction correctly? It doesn’t look at all right.